# Insert missing time rows into a dataframe

Tags: r, time-series, missing-data

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c('A','A','A','B','B','B'), 
                 time = c(1,2,4,1,2,3),
                 data = c(5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

What I want to do is insert data into the data frame where it was missing in the sequence. So in the above example, I'm missing data for `time` = 3 for group A, and `time` = 4 for Group B. I would essentially want to put 0's in the place of the `data` column.

How would I go about adding these additional rows?

The goal would be:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B'), 
                 time = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),
                 data = c(5,6,0,7,8,9,10,0))
```

My real data is a couple thousand data points, so manually doing so isn't possible.

Comment: There are lots of duplicates on *timeseries fill missing*. This is just a simpler case where the time is an integer rather than a POSIXct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `merge/expand.grid`

```
 res <- merge(
          expand.grid(group=unique(df$group), time=unique(df$time)),
                                     df, all=TRUE)
 res$data[is.na(res$data)] <- 0
 res
 #  group time data
 #1     A    1    5
 #2     A    2    6
 #3     A    3    0
 #4     A    4    7
 #5     B    1    8
 #6     B    2    9
 #7     B    3   10
 #8     B    4    0
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setkey(setDT(df), group, time)[CJ(group=unique(group), time=unique(time))
                     ][is.na(data), data:=0L]
 #    group time data
 #1:     A    1    5
 #2:     A    2    6
 #3:     A    3    0
 #4:     A    4    7
 #5:     B    1    8
 #6:     B    2    9
 #7:     B    3   10
 #8:     B    4    0
```

#### Update

As @thelatemail mentioned in the comments, the above method would fail if a particular 'time' value is not present in all the groups.  May be this would be more general.

```
 res <- merge(
          expand.grid(group=unique(df$group), 
                      time=min(df$time):max(df$time)),
                                     df, all=TRUE)
 res$data[is.na(res$data)] <- 0
```

and similarly replace `time=unique(time)` with `time= min(time):max(time)` in the data.table solution.

Comment: Nice answer, though it assumes that all possible values in the sequence are already represented in at least one of the groups. E.g. if `time = c(1,2,4,1,2,4)` this would fall over. OP should be aware of this.

Comment: @thelatemail Initially, I thought about `expand.grid(group=unique(df$group), min(df$time):max(df$time))`  I guess this would work

Comment: Thanks guys! The update worked for my much larger dataframe.