# Duplication of Rows in data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a large data.frame, which looks similar to the example below:

```
  ID date sex grade location
1  1 2000   m     1        x
2  1 2001   m     2        y
3  2 1999   f     3        z
4  2 2000   f     4        f
5  3 2000   m     5        k
6  3 2001   m     6        l
```

to reproduce it run:

```
df <- data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                     date=c(2000,2001,1999,2000,2000,2001),
                     sex = c("m", "m", "f", "f", "m", "m"),
                     grade =c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                     location =c("x","y","z", "f","k","l") )
```

I am eager to manipulate/change my data.frame to get a following structure:

```
      ID date sex grade location
    1  1 1999   m     0        0
    2  1 2000   m     1        x
    3  1 2001   m     2        y
    4  2 1999   f     3        z
    5  2 2000   f     4        f
    6  2 2001   f     0        0
    7  3 1999   m     0        0
    8  3 2000   m     5        k
    9  3 2001   m     6        l
```

Comment: Why would you want to have `0` within a character column? Wouldn't having `NA`s will make more sense? Even within a numeric column it could confuse you with real zeroes

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31150028/1191259

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with `data.table` like so:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df, key = c("ID", "date"))

> df[CJ(ID, date, unique = TRUE)]
   ID date sex grade location
1:  1 1999  NA    NA       NA
2:  1 2000   m     1        x
3:  1 2001   m     2        y
4:  2 1999   f     3        z
5:  2 2000   f     4        f
6:  2 2001  NA    NA       NA
7:  3 1999  NA    NA       NA
8:  3 2000   m     5        k
9:  3 2001   m     6        l
```

If you want to unify `sex` within `ID`:

```
df <- df[CJ(ID, date, unique = TRUE)]

df[ , sex := unique(na.omit(sex)), by = ID]
```

If you really want `0`s instead of `NA` for `grade` and `location` (you should reconsider this, as it's likely preferable to leave it as `NA`):

```
df[is.na(grade), grade := 0]
levels(df$location) <- c("0", levels(df$location))
df[is.na(location), location := "0"]
```

Comment: That's quite nice way. Is it possible to keep the values of the variable `sex` preventing it to be changed to **NA**?

Comment: @DavidArenburg neat.

Answer (score 4):

With `tidyr`, we can use `complete`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    complete(ID, date)
#    ID  date    sex grade location
#  (dbl) (dbl) (fctr) (dbl)   (fctr)
#1     1  1999     NA    NA       NA
#2     1  2000      m     1        x
#3     1  2001      m     2        y
#4     2  1999      f     3        z
#5     2  2000      f     4        f
#6     2  2001     NA    NA       NA
#7     3  1999     NA    NA       NA
#8     3  2000      m     5        k
#9     3  2001      m     6        l
```

If we need to replace the NA values in 'sex'

```
df %>% 
    complete(ID, date) %>%
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(sex= sex[!is.na(sex)][1L])
```

---

Or a `base R` option is

```
 merge(expand.grid(lapply(df[1:2], unique)), df, all.x=TRUE)
```