# Expanding long format time series data with missing Rows

Tags: r, time-series

Let's say I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(group = c('A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C'), 
time = c(1,2,4,1,2,3,5,7,8), 
data = c(5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3))
```

What I want to do is insert data into the data frame where it was missing in the sequence. So in the above example, I'm missing data for time = 3 for group A, and time = 4 for Group B and time =6 for Group C. I would essentially want to put NAs in the place of the data column.
How would I go about adding these additional rows? 
I need a generalized solution 
NOTE: I EDITED THE QUESTION AS THERE WAS AN ERROR EARLIER
WE CANNOT ASSUME THAT THERE WILL BE ONLY 4 OBSERVATIONS FOR EACH GROUP.

The goal would be:

```
  df <- data.frame(group = c('A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C'), 
    time = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,5,6,7,8), 
    data = c(5,6,NA,7,8,9,10,1,NA,2,3))
```

Comment: "So in the above example, I'm missing data for time = 3 for group A, and time = 4 for Group B and time =6 for Group C." - How do you know this? Is there another data structure that tells you this, or is there a criterion you can articulate by which you can infer this from the shown data frame?

Comment: One option is following: `df.fill = merge(df, expand.grid(group=unique(df$group), time=min(df$time):max(df$time)), all=TRUE)`. `expand.grid` creates a data frame containing all possible combinations of `group` and `time`. You merge that into your original data frame as full join (`all=TRUE` takes care of that) giving you new rows for the missing combinations.

Comment: This question seems like a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996452/r-find-and-add-missing-non-existing-rows-in-time-related-data-frame), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16787038/r-insert-rows-for-missing-dates-times), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31150028/insert-missing-time-rows-into-a-dataframe) and probably other SO questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option using `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), expand the dataset grouped by 'group' from `min` to `max` of 'time' and join `on` the 'group' and 'time' columns.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, .(time = min(time):max(time)) , by = group], on = c("group", "time")]
#    group time data
# 1:     A    1    5
# 2:     A    2    6
# 3:     A    3   NA
# 4:     A    4    7
# 5:     B    1    8
# 6:     B    2    9
# 7:     B    3   10
# 8:     C    5    1
# 9:     C    6   NA
#10:     C    7    2
#11:     C    8    3
```

Comment: I had a typo in the question